# Edit suggestions should be put to hold when another user is currently editing?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits

I was editing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940051/mysql-single-query-to-get-count-of-individual-of-past-7-days) question but it was rejected due to ["This edit is too minor"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1898164). This would be bad if I do too many edits which get rejected, since I am aware that I would be banned for 1 week if I get too many rejections.

My first concern is that I was actually making almost the same edits compared to the 1st editor. Maybe I saved it a second later so it appeared as if I only made some minor changes and it got rejected.

How can I avoid this problem? Just as a suggestion, should the post be made non-editable until the current editor saves his edit? This would prevent the second editor from getting rejections.

I also came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943009/difference-between-css-height-100-vs-height-auto) question where the edit was too trivial but it seems to have been approved.

So what sort of edits are considered as minor? Am I missing something when considering      edits to a post?

Comment: Don't just bold random parts in posts that's just invalid.

Comment: OT, but looking through your suggested edits, they are fairly poor. Don't make things bold when there is no real need. Don't skip on proper capitalization. Edit out things like "Hi" or "Thanks". And please write something more descriptive than *"please find the edits"* into your edit comments.

Comment: Thanks. How do i overcome my first concern?

Comment: @Gayu Under the current system you don't. Edit clashes happen. They are annoying, but there is not much you can do about them. I believe there is already a feature request for the editing lock you propose (or an activity indicator), so have a look around on Meta.

Comment: @Bart - Thank you. I will be careful next time not to bold unwanted things.